# Graph API - Add users in Office 365 Group

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell, office-365-groups, graph-api

How do users add in **Office 365 Group** using ***MS Graph API*** or Powershell?

Answer (score 0):

To add users to the Office 365 Group, you need to use members navigation property.

**Example** : If the group id to which you need to add member is **02bd9fd6-8f93-4758-87c3-1fb73740a315**. Then you need to use below POST query to add **abc@user.onmicrosoft.com** user to the group.

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/02bd9fd6-8f93-4758-87c3-1fb73740a315/members/$ref
Content-type: application/json

{
  "@odata.id": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/abc@user.onmicrosoft.com"
}
```

**Powershell**

```
Add-UnifiedGroupLinks –Identity "Accounts@TheCrescentTech.com" –LinkType "Members" –Links "john@TheCrescentTech.com"
```

[Adding User to Group using Powershell](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2018/05/add-members-to-office-365-group-using-powershell.html)

Comment: using pnp powershell. how can we add?

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

1. **Identity** --> The identity number of the group.
   $groupId = 02bd9fd6-8f93-4758-87c3-1fb73740a315
2. **Members** --> The array UPN values of members to set to the group. It will replace all the existing members.
   $members =  @('demo@contoso.com','demo2@contoso.com')

PnP PowerShell to add users as members in the Office 365 group:

```
Set-PnPUnifiedGroup -Identity $groupId -Members $members
```

Answer (score 0):

@Liz,

You can add user to a group via following methods:

1. [Office 365 cli](https://pnp.github.io/cli-microsoft365/cmd/aad/o365group/o365group-user-add/)
2. MS Graph API: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-1-add-a-member-to-a-group
3. AzureAD powershell for Graph:
   [Add-AzureADGroupMember](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/add-azureadgroupmember?view=azureadps-2.0),
   [Installing the Azure AD Module](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/active-directory/install-adv2?view=azureadps-2.0)
4. MSOnline V1 PowerShell
   [Add-MsolGroupMember](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/msonline/add-msolgroupmember?view=azureadps-1.0)

BR